# Inserting meta name keywords tags in wordpress for only Post types and not pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert the `meta name="keywords"` tag in my wordpress posts, But it gets inserted in all the pages starting from home page, which I do not want. I want this inserted into head tag of only Posts. I tried inserting the code in content-single.php file, but it either gets inserted to the top of the page before head tag, or inside the body tag.

```
<?php echo '<meta name='.'"'.'keywords'.'"'.' content='.'"'.'blogs to read'.'learn japanese'.'"'.'/>'?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
if ( is_single() ) {
  echo '<meta name="keywords" content="blogs to read learn japanese"/>'
}
?>
```

The `is_single()` function check if you are in a single post page.

You can paste this in your `header.php` template file.

Answer (score 2):

You could add this code into functions.php file of your theme or your child theme. I have prepared a 2 solutions for you.

1st solution is based on your custom meta description and meta keywords for each post separatelly for a better seo perfomance without any plugin. You have to just create two custom fields in your post.

wp_desc and wp_keywords are the fields as you can see on screenshot bellow.

[image]

Code for the 1st solution:

```
   function wp_seo() {
            global $post;
            if ( is_single() ) {
                $desc = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'wp_desc', true );
                $keywords = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'wp_keywords', true );
    
        // Output
        if( ! empty( $desc ) )
            printf( 
                '<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
                esc_attr( trim( $desc ) )
            );
            if( ! empty( $keywords) )
            printf( 
                '<meta name="keywords" content="%s" />',
                esc_attr( trim( $keywords ) )
            );
    }
}
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_seo' , 2 );
```

2nd solution is based on hard coded meta description and meta keywords. You could just edit the code bellow to set meta description and meta keywords. Change the `$desc = 'Here'` and `$keywords = 'Here'` with the content you want to provide as desciption and keywords.

```
function wp_seo() {
        global $post;
        if ( is_single() ) {
            $desc = 'Here'; //add your description here
            $keywords = 'Here'; //add your keywords here

    // Output
    if( ! empty( $desc ) )
        printf( 
            '<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
            esc_attr( trim( $desc ) )
        );
        if( ! empty( $keywords) )
        printf( 
            '<meta name="keywords" content="%s" />',
            esc_attr( trim( $keywords ) )
        );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_seo' , 2 );
```

Comment: Now that's elaborate and very helpful.